# Records are not coming as per requirement in mongoose node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query a criteria in mongoose on the basis of user id and receivedData company to find/populate subdocuments. But when I run the query it fetches all the records but it should only fetch one record. Below is the model and the code. In receivedData data and companyid are the two references to the data and company model.

User Model:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5534306515a734345d550c29"),
"password" : "123456789",
"email" : "abc@gmail.com",

"receivedData" : [ 
    {
        "from" : ObjectId("5535357e95ce31e04a994e2a"),
        "data" : ObjectId("553549abea87c000454fa623"),
        "companyid" : ObjectId("54d90293ec135f35379b53b7"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("5535556fea87c000454fa626"),
        "sent" : ISODate("2015-04-20T19:37:19.460Z")
    }, 
    {
        "from" : ObjectId("5535357e95ce31e04a994e2a"),
        "data" : ObjectId("55354f73ea87c000454fa624"),
        "companyid" : ObjectId("53feeaa2e4c1087e53bf4a2a"),
        "_id" : ObjectId("55f68911498231e434df53cd"),
        "sent" : ISODate("2015-09-14T08:45:05.139Z")
    }
],
```

}

Node.js Code:

```
   models.User.find({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('5534306515a734345d550c29'), receivedData: {$elemMatch: {companyid: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('53feeaa2e4c1087e53bf4a2a')}}})
    .populate('receivedData.data receivedData.from')
    .select('receivedData.data receivedData.from receivedData.companyid')
    .exec(function (err, current_user) {
        console.log(current_user);           
    })
```

Below is the output it shows

```
[ { _id: 5534306515a734345d550c29,
    receivedData: 
     [ { from: 5535357e95ce31e04a994e2a,
         data: 553549abea87c000454fa623,
         companyid: 54d90293ec135f35379b53b7 },
       { from: 5535357e95ce31e04a994e2a,
         data: 55354f73ea87c000454fa624,
         companyid: 53feeaa2e4c1087e53bf4a2a } ]
```

But I want the below output with one record:

```
 [ { _id: 5534306515a734345d550c29,
    receivedData: 
     [ { from: 5535357e95ce31e04a994e2a,
         data: 553549abea87c000454fa623,
         companyid: 53feeaa2e4c1087e53bf4a2a }]
```

I don't know why it is showing two records. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Try including the [`$` positional projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator in your `select` call field names: `.select('receivedData.$.data receivedData.$.from receivedData.$.companyid')`

Comment: @JohnnyHK. The result says undefined.